# Замер View-элементов

Tags: java, android, android-view

Пишу класс, который будет заполнять View-контейнер максимально возможным количеством указанных View-элементов. Примерно так:

```
public class LayoutFiller {

    private ViewGroup viewGroup;
    private View fillingView;

public LayoutFiller ( ViewGroup viewGroup, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, int viewAddress ) {
    setViewGroup(viewGroup);
    setFillingView( layoutInflater.inflate(viewAddress, null, false) );
    viewGroup.addView(fillingView);
```

Для того, чтобы измерить элементы до отрисовки, гугление рекомендовало задействовать либо метод measure вручную:

```
    viewGroup.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                       View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) );
    fillingView.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                         View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, ViewGroup.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) );
```

Что возвращает 424*107 для старшего элемента(правильное значение - 720*1136), и 107*54 - для младшего(это TextView, квадратный, 35dp*35dp).

Либо задействовать ViewTreeObserver, что меня не устраивает, поскольку оный возвращает размеры неизвестно когда, после onResume, а я планирую достроить этот элемент ещё в onCreate.

Есть ли какой-то способ получить более-менее корректные размеры до отрисовки элементов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаёте кастомную `view` и переопределяете в нём метод [onSizeChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), который вызывается до отрисовки но уже при известных размерах.

А по поводу определения в активности момента, когда `view` отрисован, документация гласит следующее:

> Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your
>   activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard
>   may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain
>   that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a
>   game).

Т.е. ловить момент окончания отрисовки надо в `onWindowFocusChanged()`, а не в `onResume()`  и тем более не в `onCreate()`.

Comment: В общем, проблема в том, что методы measure, onMeasure & onSizeChanged андройд вызывает после onResume. [Log](https://pastebin.com/TqwMsTgE) выглядит примерно так.
Возможен ли расчет размеров элементов (тем более, что размеры дочернего нам условно известны) на стадии onCreate?

Comment: добавил уточнение в ответ